# Entity Framework defining the foreign key

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is there a way to assign a foreign key to  the table using Entity Framework? I have following table specification using database-first (with an EDMX model file) approach:

**Table 1:**

```
classDate   
classDate_Id(pk)
classDate_reference
classDate_start
class_Id
```

**Table 2:**

```
class_Id(pk)
class_Name
classs_description
```

It is not possible to specify the class_id as a foreign key at the time of table creation (classdate). The entity table (classdate) itself with class_Id as a column (normal) not as a foreign key. I want to specify this one as foreign key. so.. is it possible to specify as a foreign key.

This is the code I found in `tsgentitesmodel.designer.cs`. Do I need to change here?

```
  public partial class tsgEntities : ObjectContext
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectSet<classdate> classdates
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_classdates == null))
            {
                _classdates = base.CreateObjectSet<classdate>("classdates");
            }
            return _classdates;
        }
    }
    private ObjectSet<classdate> _classdates;

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    public ObjectSet<@class> classes
    {
        get
        {
            if ((_classes == null))
            {
                _classes = base.CreateObjectSet<@class>("classes");
            }
            return _classes;
        }
    }
    private ObjectSet<@class> _classes;
 }

     /// <summary>
    /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the classdates EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddToclassdates(classdate classdate)
    {
        base.AddObject("classdates", classdate);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deprecated Method for adding a new object to the classes EntitySet. Consider using the .Add method of the associated ObjectSet&lt;T&gt; property instead.
    /// </summary>
    public void AddToclasses(@class @class)
    {
        base.AddObject("classes", @class);
    }
```

And I have found the below code and do I need to change here

```
 public partial class classdate : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new classdate object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="classDate_End">Initial value of the classDate_End property.</param>
    /// <param name="classDate_Id">Initial value of the classDate_Id property.</param>
    /// <param name="classDate_Reference">Initial value of the classDate_Reference property.</param>
    /// <param name="classDate_Start">Initial value of the classDate_Start property.</param>
    /// <param name="class_Id">Initial value of the class_Id property.</param>
    public static classdate Createclassdate(global::System.String classDate_End, global::System.Int32 classDate_Id, global::System.String classDate_Reference, global::System.String classDate_Start, global::System.Int32 class_Id)
    {
        classdate classdate = new classdate();
        classdate.classDate_End = classDate_End;
        classdate.classDate_Id = classDate_Id;
        classdate.classDate_Reference = classDate_Reference;
        classdate.classDate_Start = classDate_Start;
        classdate.class_Id = class_Id;
        return classdate;
    }

    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 class_Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _class_Id;
        }
        set
        {
            Onclass_IdChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("class_Id");
            _class_Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("class_Id");
            Onclass_IdChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _class_Id;
    partial void Onclass_IdChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void Onclass_IdChanged();

  // same like this for all columns in calss data table
```

Below is the code for class entity:

```
  /// <summary>
/// No Metadata Documentation available.
/// </summary>
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="tsgEntities", Name="class")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class @class : EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new class object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="class_Description">Initial value of the class_Description property.</param>
    /// <param name="class_Id">Initial value of the class_Id property.</param>
    /// <param name="class_Name">Initial value of the class_Name property.</param>
    /// <param name="class_NumSessions">Initial value of the class_NumSessions property.</param>
    /// <param name="class_Reference">Initial value of the class_Reference property.</param>
    public static @class Createclass(global::System.String class_Description, global::System.Int32 class_Id, global::System.String class_Name, global::System.String class_NumSessions, global::System.String class_Reference)
    {
        @class @class = new @class();
        @class.class_Description = class_Description;
        @class.class_Id = class_Id;
        @class.class_Name = class_Name;
        @class.class_NumSessions = class_NumSessions;
        @class.class_Reference = class_Reference;
        return @class;
    }

    #endregion
    #region Primitive Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String class_Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _class_Description;
        }
        set
        {
            Onclass_DescriptionChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("class_Description");
            _class_Description = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("class_Description");
            Onclass_DescriptionChanged();
        }
    }
    private global::System.String _class_Description;
    partial void Onclass_DescriptionChanging(global::System.String value);
    partial void Onclass_DescriptionChanged();


    //same like this for all coulmns
```

Comment: @Eranga i dont know how to specify the foreign key in entityframework..... i found the code i have mentioned in above in  tsgentitesmodel.designer.cs and i have doubt do i need to specify in that code...

Comment: @eranga would you pls help on this..

Comment: can any one help on this one... pls

Comment: @marc_s my problem is this .. I have defined primary key class_id in table 2 ,unfortunately i am not specified this primary key as foreign key in table 1 so the entity model it self taken that class_id as a normal column in  table 1 so is there any way to do that and i have already defined primary key for that...

Comment: Sorry - I just realized it's not clear what approach you're using; database-first (with an EDMX model file), or code-first (with "just" POCO classes as the defining element). Also: if you do database-first: it would be extremely helpful to know the **datatypes** of your columns in the tables! Also: what are the primary keys on those two tables??

Comment: i am bit confusion in defining  public class nefdinners:DBcontext {public DBSet <dinner> dinners {get; set;} public DBSet <rsvp> rsvps {get; set;}}  what i need place for this entire method and i am not using asp.net mvc i am using winforms..

Comment: @Marc_s I am using database-first approach first i have defined the database ...

Comment: i will update my question....

Comment: @Marc_s i have modified my question i have indicated primary keys in both tables.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a relationship between `Table2` and `Table1` on `class_Id`, that column needs to be the primary key in `Table1` - or you need to put a UNIQUE INDEX on it:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UIX01_ClassDates ON dbo.ClassDates(class_Id)
```

And then you should be able to create the foreign key relationship between your two tables:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Classes
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_classes_classdates
FOREIGN KEY (Class_Id) REFERENCES dbo.ClassDates(class_Id)
```

Now, once you've done that, refresh your EDMX model file and that relationship ought to show up automagically, now! (or you can manually add an Association between your two classes to make it show up)

Comment: where i need add this code .........ALTER TABLE dbo.Classes 
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_classes_classdates 
FOREIGN KEY (Class_Id) REFERENCES dbo.ClassDates(class_Id) ...

Comment: @user899271: you have to run these statements once - e.g. in SQL Server Management Studio. **After that**, refresh (or recreate) your EF model in your application